# k-outerplanar graphs are subgraphs of bounded diameter planar graphs? of bounded diameter bounded genus graphs?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

It is well known that bounded diameter planar graphs have bounded treewidth (e.g. see [this](http://igitur-archive.library.uu.nl/math/2006-1214-201709/bodlaender_88_planar_graphs.pdf)). Does the converse hold? That is, is every planar bounded treewidth graph the (induced?) subgraph of a bounded diameter planar graph?

I am interested in a proof sketch/reference if this is true or a counterexample if this is false.

Note1: David's correct answer below is in the negative. In its light can we modify the question to read: Are k-outerplanar graphs subgraphs of simultaneously bounded diameter and bounded genus graphs?

Note2: David further indicates (correctly) that the nested triangles graph cannot be made bounded tree-width even at the expense of increasing the genus to a constant.

Comment: I'd recommend posting your followup as a separate question that references this one (since this question is essentially resolved)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No: see the [nested triangles graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_triangles_graph). It has bounded treewidth (more strongly, bounded pathwidth and bandwidth) but cannot be augmented to have bounded diameter while preserving planarity.

Comment: A followup question: what if we replace planar by bounded genus above? I.e. k-outerplanar graphs are subgraphs of bounded diameter bounded genus graphs?

Comment: Do you have a way of reducing the diameter of the nested triangles graph below linear by adding edges while keeping the genus bounded?

Comment: No. You are correct, I can't think of such a way.